# Why does this code output a literal "\n" instead of a newline?

Tags: c++

What is the output of this following code?

```
std::cout<<"what is the output \\n hello \'world\' world";
```

I think the output should be:

```
what is the output
hello 'world' world
```

But the actual output is `the output \n hello 'world' world`

Why isn't `\n` output as a new line?

Comment: Are we going to get a lot of these from you?

Comment: Because \\ will output a single \. You can use `std::endl` to get the effect you want: `std::cout << "what is the output" << std::endl << "hello \'world\' world";`

Comment: @cong: he means that this is a fairly basic question that any good C++ book would give you answers too, and for learning C++ that is still the best option, a good book.

Comment: I guess that @unapersson means that this question, as well as your previous one, is rather basic. You might benefit from reading through some good introductory books or tutorials on c++. Then most of these questions will be automatically answered for you. Hope that helps. ;)

Comment: @sitnik: `endl` will also flush the stream, which often is not what you want.

Comment: Why is everyone jumping in to say what (they think) I mean? For all they know, I may be looking forward  with rapt attention for more posts from this user.

Comment: And there are lots of good books listed athere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list.

Answer (score 10):

Your double backslash `\\` is an escape that produces `\` so you see `\n`.  If you want a newline, use a single backslash `\n`.

Answer (score 4):

`\n` specifies a new line character. But what happens if you want a backslash character? For this, C++ allows you to use `\\`. The first backslash *escapes* the second resulting in a single backslash and no special translation.

That's what you have here, followed by `n`.